# Retrieving a property of a JSON object by index

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON Object as follows:

```
[
  {
    "Under 10": "0",
    "10-20": "1",
    "20-30": "3",
    "30-40": "2",
    "40-50": "4",
    "50-60": "4",
    "60-70": "1",
    "Above 70": "0"
  }
]
```

Is there anyway to access just individual properties of this object? I want to make each of them a separate JSON object.
I want it to look like this

```
[
  {
  "Under 10": "0"
  },
  {
  "10-20": "1",
  },
]
```

I tried using Oject.keys but it wasn't possible. I tried even with map function.

Comment: Why is the original object an array? Are there multiple objects in that array and if so, what should the transformed result look like?

Comment: Also, show what you tried and where you're having problems

Comment: *"Is there anyway to access just individual properties of this object?"* 
Well yes, that's the point of an object. Are you wanting to restructure because you think that's what's needed to access individual properties?

Comment: It's just one object. I have described above what it should look like

Comment: I see your description. You're also asking if it's possible to access individual properties, so I don't know if your description of what it should look like is motivated by you not knowing if individual properties were accessible.

Comment: @squint - No. I need to restructure because I have to input it in a certain format for a chart. The desired format is as shown above.

Comment: I see. `Object.keys()` should work. You just need to iterate the resulting array, and use the key to access the property from the original object. When creating the new object, you need to create it first, and then add the key/value pair.

Comment: @RJP no, it's not *"just one object"*, it's an array of objects with one object in it (for now). Why is it an array at all? What do you want the result to look like if there's more than one object in the array?

Comment: `arr.reduce((acc,obj) => acc.concat(Object.keys(obj).map(key => { return {[key]: obj[key] }})), [])` or with lodash `_.flatMap(arr, obj => Object.keys(obj).map(key => { return {[key]: obj[key] }}))`

Comment: Keep in mind that there's no guarantee that the resulting Array will be in the same order provided in the JSON data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using map:

```
var obj = YOUR OBJECT...

var a = Object.keys(obj[0]).map(function(key) {
  return {[key]: obj[0][key]}
});
```

quick demo: https://jsbin.com/mapoqo/1/edit?js,console

Comment: This works perfectly. If I wanted to make them into separate arrays instead of JSON objects what do you suggest doing?

Comment: what exactly do you mean, and array like: [key, value] ? what exactly would that output look like?

Comment: something like this [
    [
        "Under 10",
        "5"
    ],
    [
        "10-20",
        "3"
    ],
    [
        "20-30",
        "3"
    ]
    
]

Comment: instead of whats returned above, return `[key, obj[0][key]]` : https://jsbin.com/mapoqo/2/edit?js,console

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` or `Object.keys()`. The former returns **all** own properties while the later is a bit more specific and returns only the **enumerable** properties. For JSON it shouldn't matter, though.

```js
var json = [
  {
    "Under 10": "0",
    "10-20": "1",
    "20-30": "3",
    "30-40": "2",
    "40-50": "4",
    "50-60": "4",
    "60-70": "1",
    "Above 70": "0"
  }
];

var result = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(json[0]).map(name => ({[name]: json[0][name]}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your expected result,below option might help you

```
        var x = [
    {
        "Under 10": "0",
        "10-20": "1",
        "20-30": "3",
        "30-40": "2",
        "40-50": "4",
        "50-60": "4",
        "60-70": "1",
        "Above 70": "0"
    }]
    ;

    var keys =Object.keys(x[0]);
    var final=[];

    for(i=0;i< keys.length;i++){
     final[i] = '[{'+keys[i]+':'+x[0][keys[i]]+'}]';

    }


    console.log(final);//final array will have expected result
```

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/KMMbMm

Answer (score 0):

The original JSON is an Array and we need to convert the first Object in the Array to a new Array. As below,

```
// Original JSON, an Array.
var raw = [ 
  {
    "Under 10": "0",
    "10-20": "1",
    "20-30": "3",
    "30-40": "2",
    "40-50": "4",
    "50-60": "4",
    "60-70": "1",
    "Above 70": "0"
  }
];

// The first Object in original JSON(an Array).
var oldObject = raw[0]; 

// New Array stores the Objects you want.
var newArray = []; 

// Get each item in oldObject
for(var key in oldObject) { 

  // Create a new Object
  var obj = {}; 

  // Assign the value of key of oldObject to obj[key].
  // Like obj["Under 10"] = "0".
  obj[key] = oldObject[key];  

  // Append obj to newArray.
  newArray.push(obj);

}
```

Anyway, **newArray** is what you need.
Cheers :)